# gRPC WaitForConnected always return true

Tags: c++, grpc

I have grpc server and grpc client solution running as 2 separate services. If the client comes up first, it tries to connect to grpc server and if server is not up, it suppose to wait. I thought `WaitForConnected` is defined for this purpose. It looks like it's not working correctly.

My Code:

```
    if (!channel->WaitForConnected(gpr_time_add(
              gpr_now(GPR_CLOCK_REALTIME),
              gpr_time_from_seconds(600, GPR_TIMESPAN)))) {
        //Log error and return
      }
     grpc_connectivity_state state = channel->GetState(true);
     // cout << state always return 2 (GRPC_CHANNEL_READY) even if server is not up.
```

Grpc version: 1.6.x

Answer (score 0):

Are you running inside a docker container? Be aware that `docker-proxy` accepts connections, even if the port inside the container hast not opened its port.

You can test this by creating a dummy port mapping, e.g.: `docker run --rm -it -p 1234:1234 $my-image`. Even if the image does not open the port, `docker-proxy` will open it and accepts connections made to it. Yout can use the `--net=host` option as a workaround. It does not use the proxy.